# Consulta SQL con rango de fechas dinámico

Tags: sql

Estoy generando un reporte usando sql en un sistema administrativo. El reporte debe permitir al usuario indicar un rango de fechas. ¿Cómo hacer la consulta?

[image: la primer imagen es como aparece al usuario para indicar fecha y hora]

```sql
FROM DOCTOS_PV DOCTOS_PV_1
      LEFT OUTER JOIN DOCTOS_PV_COBROS DOCTOS_PV_COBROS_1 ON 
     (DOCTOS_PV_COBROS_1.DOCTO_PV_ID = DOCTOS_PV_1.DOCTO_PV_ID)
      INNER JOIN FORMAS_COBRO FORMAS_COBRO_1 ON 
     (FORMAS_COBRO_1.FORMA_COBRO_ID = DOCTOS_PV_COBROS_1.FORMA_COBRO_ID)
WHERE ( DOCTOS_PV_1.TIPO_DOCTO = 'V' )
       AND ( FORMAS_COBRO_1.NOMBRE LIKE 'Efectivo%' )
       and  ( dOCTOS_PV_1.FECHA + DOCTOS_PV_1.HORA >= '03/06/2024 ' )
       AND ( DOCTOS_PV_1.FECHA + DOCTOS_PV_1.HORA <= '03/07/2024 ' )
```

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. ¿Qué SGBD/DBMS estás utilizando? ¿MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server? Ponlo en las etiquetas. Además, ¿qué problema tuviste con la consulta que estás mostrando? Muestra también un [repro] del formulario de carga de los parámetros.

Comment: Aparte de lo que dijo el usuario de arriba, ¿Por qué estas sumando fechas? Yo te diría que hagas un SP que reciba los parámetros de fecha que necesitas y listo

Comment: Cada implementación de SQL maneja las fechas de forma distinta. Es por eso que es importante saber cual manejador estás usando para poder dar una solución adecuada.

Comment: para buscar entre fechas puedes usar WHERE column_name BETWEEN fach1 AND vfecha2

Comment: ¿Cuáles de los campos input son obligatorios, cuáles son opcionales? ¿Por qué tienes fechas y horas separadas en tu tabla, en vez de tener campos combinados de datetime? ¿Cuáles de los campos para fecha y hora en tu tabla son obligatorios, cuáles son opcionales? Y cuidado: Esto no es una fecha, es una cadena de caracteres: `'03/06/2024 '`. ¿De qué tipos son tus campos de fecha y hora en la tabla?

Answer (score 0):

Si tu problema es buscar entre un rango de fechas Guarda en una varible la fecha inicial.  Digamos FechaInicial
Luego en otra variable guardas la fecha final.  Digamos FechaFinal

Ahora adapta tu select de la siguiente manera

```
FROM DOCTOS_PV DOCTOS_PV_1
      LEFT OUTER JOIN DOCTOS_PV_COBROS DOCTOS_PV_COBROS_1 ON 
     (DOCTOS_PV_COBROS_1.DOCTO_PV_ID = DOCTOS_PV_1.DOCTO_PV_ID)
      INNER JOIN FORMAS_COBRO FORMAS_COBRO_1 ON 
     (FORMAS_COBRO_1.FORMA_COBRO_ID = DOCTOS_PV_COBROS_1.FORMA_COBRO_ID)
WHERE ( DOCTOS_PV_1.TIPO_DOCTO = 'V' )
       AND ( FORMAS_COBRO_1.NOMBRE LIKE 'Efectivo%' )
       AND ( DOCTOS_PV_1.FECHA + DOCTOS_PV_1.HORA) BETWEEN FechaInial AND FechaFinal
```

Comment: _Cada implementación de SQL maneja las fechas de forma distinta_. Aguarda a que OP aclare qué SGBD está utilizando. Lee [answer].